# Windows 8.1 Very quiet headphones

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, headphones

I have a Toshiba Satellite L755 running Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu, and I recently encountered a problem with my headphones. Earlier, after restarting, the headphones (plugged into the jack, not a USB port) suddenly became very quiet. If I have it on max volume, I can barely hear some sound, but only just. I've tried installing the Realtek drivers, but that didn't work. This is the second time this has happened. The first time, it seemed to magically fix itself (after messing with some headphone settings and installing Realtek drivers), but then it just now happened again after an OS update.

I am sure that the headphones aren't damaged: they work fine with my phone: it's only the laptop that it has trouble with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the levels in Volume Mixer? Right-click on the speaker icon in the task bar to find it.

Comment: I have yes. It doesn't have anything that seems odd to me (everything is at max volume).

Comment: Are the speakers quiet too?

Comment: My speakers are non-functional - it's been that way for a while, and is most likely unrelated to this problem.

Comment: I don't have Realtek drivers installed on this computer to look for it, but is it possible that it is set to use the headphone jack as "Line out" instead of "Headphones" or "Speakers"? Line out will give a smaller voltage than other settings.

Comment: Where would I check that? I can't find anywhere to change Realtek settings.

Comment: When you installed the Realtek drivers it probably installed a program called "Realtek HD Audio Manager", it should be somewhere in that. I'm looking at the [instructions for it](http://ftp.serdica.org/public/drivers/Motherboards/ASUS/A55BM/Manual/Audio/English/English/E_Realtek_Audio_v4.0_DTS.pdf), but it appears that the options you get are dependent on the computer's hardware, so you may have to look around a bit.

Comment: It does not seem to be visible anywhere. It's not in program files (32 bit or 64 bit), it's not in the control panel, and it's not in the notification area.

Comment: @CreeperInATardis OK, you can just download and install it then. There might be a specific version for your computer, so it is best if you first check on Toshiba's website for it. Oh! It looks like you maybe you should have Conexant drivers, not Realtek ones: [Satellite L755-S5216 Support](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=3025152) - N.B. do make sure you go to the support page for your exact model, not necessarily that one.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you. I feel like I had Realtek when I had Windows 7 installed... I'll try that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Morton figured it out. I installed the correct Conexant (NOT REALTEK) drivers from the Toshiba website and restarted, and it works.

Comment: Thanks for adding your own answer for "closure" on the question.  In two days, you will be able to accept it, which will flag the problem as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question by Googling. The "volume mixer" comment helped me to figure out that Windows had selected my headset in "hands free mode" (like it was a cell phone, in mono). I changed it to "stereo" mode in the "Playback Devices" control panel (right click on the speaker icon in the lower right) by selecting "stereo" mode and changing it to the "default" device. The sound is definitely full power now. Thanks.